# Assinatura de string em base64

Tags: c#, xml, assinatura-digital

Em meu projeto, tenho uma regra que preciso assinar a string de um *XML* que tenho que está em *base64* com o CPF do usuário...

Andei pesquisando, mas não consegui entender direito como que funciona essa assinatura de uma *string* com classes do próprio **.NET**.

Bem, achei [esse link aqui](http://nf-eletronica.com/blog/?p=47) que faz a assinatura de uma *string* de um *XML* de NF-e. Mas não consegui entender direito como que funciona, e nem como adaptar esse código desse tamanho para o meu cenário.

O que tenho até agora: Gero o *XML*, escrevo no arquivo e consigo gerar o *hash* *base64* dessa *string*, mas o que me falta agora é assinar essa *string* com o *CPF* da pessoa.

Os códigos que tenho são:

```
//Cria o xml com as tags e faz o encoding para base64
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
string cpf = "000.001.000-00";

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
{
    //Inicia o documetno xml
    writer.WriteStartDocument();

    //escreve o documento raiz
    writer.WriteStartElement("no1");

    //escreve os subelementos
    writer.WriteElementString("no2", "valor");

    //encerra o elemento raiz
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    //escreve o xml para o arquivo e encerra o objeto escritor
    writer.Close();
}

//encoding do xml para base64
string s = EncodeTo64(sb.ToString());

//arquivo que vai ser usado para gerar a string base64      
string caminho = parametros.Propriedades["ParPastaArquivoXML"].ToString();
caminho = caminho + "\\" + "arquivo.xml";

File.WriteAllText(caminho, s);
```

Aqui tenta assinar:

```
try
   {
       // Create a new CspParameters object to specify 
       // a key container.
       CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
       cspParams.KeyContainerName = cpf;

       // Create a new RSA signing key and save it in the container. 
       RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

       // Create a new XML document.
       XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

       // Load an XML file into the XmlDocument object.
       xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
       xmlDoc.Load(caminho);

       // Sign the XML document. 
       SignXml(xmlDoc, rsaKey);

       Console.WriteLine("XML file signed.");

       // Save the document.
       xmlDoc.Save(caminhoAssinado);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
   }
```

Aqui o método para assinar:

```
// Sign an XML file.  
// This document cannot be verified unless the verifying  
// code has the key with which it was signed. 
public static void SignXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc, RSA Key)
{
    // Check arguments. 
    if (xmlDoc == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("xmlDoc");
    if (Key == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Key");

    // Create a SignedXml object.
    SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

    // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
    signedXml.SigningKey = Key;

    // Create a reference to be signed.
    Reference reference = new Reference();
    reference.Uri = "";

    // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
    XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
    reference.AddTransform(env);

    // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
    signedXml.AddReference(reference);

    // Compute the signature.
    signedXml.ComputeSignature();

    // Get the XML representation of the signature and save 
    // it to an XmlElement object.
    XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

    // Append the element to the XML document.
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
}
```

O exemplo de *XML* que é criado segue abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<no1>
  <no2>021303</no2>
</no1>
```

Até esse momento eu consigo gerar o *hash base64*.

Mas agora, como que eu faço para assinar esse *hash* com o *CPF*?

Comment: Quando você pergunta : "como faço para assinar esse hash com o CPF", você quer dizer como assinar com um certificado digital de pessoa física? Tipo e-CPF A3 instalado na máquina do usuário?

Comment: Isso mesmo @GuilhermeJSantos. Com esse certificado de Pessoa Física. Ele já está instalado na máquina, mas não to conseguindo assinar pra enviar pro webservice... E na hora de enviar o webservice me retorna o erro de que não está lendo o CPF no arquivo.

Comment: Erik, o arquivo de exemplo me parece correto, do link que você passou. Você conseguiu rodar ele? Se sim, deu algum erro? Para NFe você precisa de um certificado específico de pessoa jurídica, veja em: http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/perguntasFrequentes.aspx?tipoConteudo=k/E5BakB80o=

Comment: Até onde eu saiba, para assinatura de NFe você precisa de um certificado para CNPJ (e-CNPJ) ou o de NFe (e-NFE).

Comment: Eu usei o link da NF-e, como exemplo, mas não estou assinando uma NF-e, e sim um xml com um número específico para o webservice me responder com outro xml populado com dados pra que eu possa tratar no meu sistema interno... Peguei o link mais como exemplo de código mesmo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cara, desenvolvo soluções para NF-e, tenho o seguinte código de assinatura, não sei se para o *CPF* pode ser o mesmo padrão, se sim, funciona assim:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();   // <---- aqui declaro um novo xml
xml.LoadXml(sbXml.ToString()); // <-- carrego o xml que quero assinar, no meu caso, dependendo do xml a montar, uso um StringBuilder doc pequenos

var i = 0;
var docXML = new SignedXml(xml); // <-- instancia classe de criptografia

docXML.SigningKey = NFe_Rec.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate.PrivateKey; // <--adiciono o certificado digital, instanciado o serviço que vou usar no caso "NFe_Rec", que ira  para autenticar a operação e atribuindo a docXML.SigningKey.

var refer = new Reference(); // <-- Adicionando Reference

refer.Uri = "#ID" + (CASO O PADRÃO DO DOC FISCAL SEJA O MESMO, O CPF VEM AQUI); // <-- Essa é palavra chave
refer.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
refer.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());
docXML.AddReference(refer); 

var ki = new KeyInfo();
ki.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(NFe_Rec.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate));
docXML.KeyInfo = ki; // <-- refente a algumas computações e tags especificas do padrão X509 que são adicionados.

docXML.ComputeSignature(); // <-- calcula e assinatura,com base no arquivo xml lá em cima e Uri que informamos;
i++;

xml.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[i].AppendChild(xml.ImportNode(docXML.GetXml(), true)); // <-- aqui adiciona dentro do node que quiser a assinatura, nas NF(s), ficam dentro da tag <NFe> depois de todos os outros childs do node.
```

Isso para documentos fiscais, porém não chequei mais a ideia deve ser a mesma.

Seu *doc* ficaria assim, seguindo o modelo de assinatura que mostrei:

```
<CPF>
<infCPF Id="CPF00000000000">
//aqui ficaria as tags com informações que você gostaria de transmitir.
</infCPF> // Logo depois assinatura, essa assinatura
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><Reference URI="#CPF00000000000"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><DigestValue>cwWi6+IRhijWDsJxA1SgL0P9Dsk=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo>q78y4IqMDFi070dX+foGJIABgd3/s7Du9glN2sZQh9JJfSFdwH1Evh1PtigN9dc7aSxNdha6/n8/7kWQFjv8=</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></CPF>
```

Comment: Cara, não entendi essa parte aqui: ` refer.Uri = "#ID" + (CASO O PADRÃO DO DOC FISCAL SEJA O MESMO, O CPF VEM AQUI); <-- Essa é palavra chave`. Poderia me explicar ?

Comment: sim claro, a uri serve com a chave para criptografar o documento inteiro, se fosse uma nota fiscal seria a chave de 44 caracteres, como o seu intuito é  assinar o documento utilizando o CPF será o numero do cpf.

Comment: Aaaaah ta! Nossa agora ficou bem claro... Muito obrigado! Só uma outra dúvida... Eu teria que ter uma tag no XML para o número do CPF ?

Comment: teria que ter como atributo em uma tag, vou acionar, um exemplo de como seu documento xml ficaria.

Comment: Ohhh cara, seria ótimo!

Comment: No exemplo xml temos, a tag root, CPF, dai temos a tag, infCPF que iria os outros conjuntos de nodes e childs que informaria, nesta mesma tag, tem o id, que é o palavra chave(lembrando que o certificado é exigido para assinar um documento), depois Signature, assinatura do arquivo.

Comment: Se você utilizar o mesmo padrão que se usa em uma nfe, utilizando certificado A1 ou A3 para assinar o doc, no seu caso funcionaria numa boa.

Comment: To testando aqui pra ver se funciona... @bp002

Comment: tudo bem, aparecendo mais duvidas só perguntar.

Comment: aqui: `NFe_Rec`, o que seria ? Um certificado instalado no pc ?

Comment: Não, se  trata de um serviço que preciso instanciar da receita federal, e para usar ele é necessário certificado.

Comment: Aaaah ta. Entendi!